# How to get correct screen resolution?

Tags: c#, forms

My laptop screen resolution is 1920 * 1080. But the following calls gives a different resolution - 1280 * 720. How can I get the correct screen resolution? I use Windows 10

```
int height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
int width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;

width = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width;
height = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height;
```

Comment: The setting in windows is 1920x1080, right?

Comment: @John - Yes. I called SetProcessDPIAware and now the resolution is getting properly

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is almost correct with the first one.

Here is how you should code it

```
        int height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size.Height;
        int width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size.Width;
```